# reference request: product measures defined by a subsequence of measures

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\{\mu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of pairwise equivalent probability measures, each of which is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\bigotimes_n\mu_n$ be the product measure defined on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Are there papers that discuss the existence of a proper subsequence $\{\mu_{n_i}\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\{\mu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mu_{n_i}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu_n$? I am specifically interested in the case where each $\mu_n$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ and is defined by (one or more) parameters. For instance, each $\mu_n$ is a geometric distribution defined by $\rho_n$ for some $\rho_n\in(0, 1)$ and $\{\rho_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a distinct sequence of parameters.